# C++ left and right reference for return value

Tags: c++11, rvalue

The following code is running in MSVC and I write my question inline the code below.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Object
{
    Object() = default;

    Object(const Object &o)
    {
        std::cout << "left value constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Object(Object &&o)
    {
        std::cout << "right value constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

void jn(Object &o)
{
    std::cout << "left reference jn" << std::endl;
}

void jn(Object &&o)
{
    std::cout << "right reference jn" << std::endl;
}

Object go;

Object gn()
{
    Object &&rgo = std::move(go);
    jn(rgo); // left reference jn is called, so rgo should be left reference
    return rgo; // right reference constructor is called, so rgo should be right reference
    // Question: rgo is left reference or right reference? Why left reference version jn is called while Object move constructor is called in return statement?
}

int main()
{
    gn();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I notice the difference behavior between gcc and msvc. https://godbolt.org/z/q519vxqxo

Comment: `rgo` is an lvalue. To the first approximation, if an object has a name, it's an lvalue; if it's an unnamed temporary, it's an rvalue. The main reason for this is that a temporary is going to be destroyed soon anyway, so it's OK to take resources from it; whereas a named object can be observed afterwards. Now, there's a special dispensation for `return someName;`, where `someName` is a local variable; this statement could treat `someName` as an rvalue if possible, because the function is about to return and the local variable is about to be destroyed, and so it can be treated like a temporary.

Comment: In your godbolt example, add `-std=c++20` option to observe [newer behavior](https://godbolt.org/z/KsaYdTnMf). I'm not sure why this requires C++20 though; I was under impression that the special case for `return` statement was introduced in C++17 or even C++14.